# Detect keypress in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, handler, cell

I am using following code to detect keypresses in a datagridview:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_mt_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1_mt.EditingControlShowing
     AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cell_Keydown
End Sub

Private Sub cell_Keydown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space And CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        e.Handled = True
        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("_")
    End If
End Sub
```

basically I need to replace every space with an underscore. The code is working so far except for 2 problems:

1) e.handled does not seem to affect the output. There is Always a space In front of the underscore. how can I prevent it from typing it?

2) Each time i change cell a new handler is added, and if I am editing for example the fifth cell the result will be a space followed by 5 underscores. How can I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to handle the `CellBeginEdit` or the `CellEndEdit` along? When you press a key while a cell is selected in a `DataGridView`, the `CellBeginEdit` is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this way:

```
Dim eventhandleradded As Boolean = False

Private Sub DataGridView1_mt_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1_mt.EditingControlShowing
    If eventhandleradded = False Then
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cell_Keydown
        eventhandleradded = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cell_Keydown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space And CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        e.Handled = True
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("_")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Won't this continue to add handlers over and over again?

Comment: nope because the vairable is global, and once set to true there is nothing setting it back to false again.

Comment: You use `RemoveHandler` statement in the event and that will remove the delegate.

Comment: It's best to use: `If e.Control.KeyDown Is Nothing Then AddHandler...` An event handler shall never be null (or Nothing) when a handler is assigned to it. This way, you no longer need the global variable, and makes your intention clearer, IMHO.